# Robust handling of the pager in an Ajax controlled View, when URI is shared with another user?

Tags: views, javascript

I have a gallery content type, it references a number of images. When viewing gallery content, a View renders a gallery image, and a pager set to display a single item at a time allows the user to go back and forth with a link that will *change the url*.

As a user, I can now copy the URL and send it to someone else, who will see exactly the same image.

Problems show up however, when we decide to load *only* the new image, instead of the whole page, with JS. Since we no longer change the url, the JS-using user will remain at `page=0` all the time, and can no longer share this URL as intended.

I have two suggestions of my own, but I haven't implemented either yet, and would love to hear either comments on those, different answers, or just votes on whichever answer you think is the best.

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript, I could manipulate the `#` value of the URL without triggering a page reload. Using this, a custom Javascript pager could be implemented, that will override the `?page` value with any `#page` value instead. Unfortunately that would mean loading two images. This way, paging with JS will update the `#page` value, and this url can then shared and get the intended behavior.

Comment: I haven't implemented a custom pager for views before, but does it work on the client side? The `#` part of a URL isn't sent to the server so there would have to be some client-side manipulation/loading of the view whenever the `#` portion of the url changes, or whenever a page is visited directly

Comment: Your right, I didn't consider that. A custom pager doesn't make sense at all then. Unless you'll do it, I'll post a different suggestion then.

Comment: I think it's still valid, just not the `#` part...for HTML5 browsers it is possible to [modify the url without refreshing the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page); it seems you might be able to use that technique in place of the `#` if that makes sense?

Comment: Yeah, but the custom "paging" would need to be implemented client side instead, so that a link to ?page=Y#page=X will start at Y, but then move to X. I've updated the answer to remove the Views reference.

Answer (score 0):

When using Javascript, the next/previous button could manipulate the `#` part of the URL with a `page=X` variable, and then if this is sent somewhere using a service like facebook or twitter, we just parse the `#page=X` into `?page=Y` instead. If the url is copied directly, then we manipulate the copied text with JS to remove the `#` and move it's value into `?`.

I believe I've seen such JS url-mangling practices before, but I also though that browsers protected the clipboard from manipulation with JS.